# jQuery 2.0.2 doesnt work in IE8 - code compatible?

Tags: jquery, ie8

I know jQuery 2.0 doesn't support IE8.

Is there a way to change the j Query code in our JS file, to ensure jQuery 2.0.2 for compatibility with IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use Jquery 2 if you want to Support IE8? In the Notes of Jquery 2.x you can find

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

So: Change to Jquery 1.x if you want to Support IE8